# How do I sort in alphabetical order this SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sorting

I have tried with sort() in front of $new but it won't work, where should I put it?

```
$new = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM Professors");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($new)) {  

    $output .= "{$row['Field']}";
    echo $output;
}
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
  $new = "SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE   table_name = 'Professors' ORDER BY column_name";
```

but, while on my SQL compiler it will sort them correctly, they won't get printed on the page with the exact code above.

Comment: `ORDER BY ASC` or `DESC`

Comment: Try your select, but output "{row['column_name']}"

Comment: @Ivke it will say:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075800/sql-listing-all-column-names-alphabetically

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw, nice suggestion but you forgot the `$` before row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, then:

```
 $new = "SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE   table_name = 'Professors' ORDER BY column_name";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($new)) {  
    $output = $row['column_name'] . "<br>";
    echo $output;
}
```

You were ordering it correctly and selecting by column name but you weren't getting the correct field names.

Comment: @paul grimshaw it will output {row['column_name']} as text

Comment: Whenever you need. Don't forget to pick the accepted question.